# Orthogonal family in Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(x_k)_1^\infty$ be an orthogonal family of points in X a Hilbert space.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$ converges if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty ||x_k||^2$ converges.  Also need to show that $$\big|\big|\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_k \big|\big|^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty ||x_k||^2.$$
My Attempt:
Since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_k<\infty$ converges then $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_k\cdot\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_k=(x_1+x_2+...)(x_1+x_2+...)=x_1\cdot x_1+x_2 \cdot x_2 + ...=\sum_{i=1}^\infty||x_k||^2<\infty$$ Now middle of the previous line is true because $x_1 \cdot x_2=0$.  If my statement is true then I am pretty much done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, basically that's it, but rigorously we should use this only for finite summands.

Let $s_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, and suppose it converges to $s:=\lim s_n$, that is, $\|s_n-s\|\to 0$. By orthogonality, as you said, we have
$$\|s_n\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\|x_i\|^2$$
and *by the continuity* of norm, we also have $\|s_n\|\to\|s\|$.

Since $\lim \|s_n\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\|^2$, we obtain that this latter series also converges (to $\|s\|^2$).

On the other hand, if $\sum_n \|x_n\|^2=+\infty$, it also means that $\|s_n\|^2\to\infty$, and therefore $s_n$ can't be convergent.